# Solving linear simultaneous equations with 7 unknowns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to solve a system of 7 linear equations to complete a step involved in a "Transhipment Simplex Algorithm" problem. I have written the following code using the numpy library:

```
import numpy as np 

# Coefficients matrix
A = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0,1,0]]

# RHS matrix
B = [0,120,100,40,10,60,100]

# Solution matrix
X = np.linalg.inv(A).dot(B)
print (X)
```

However, when I run this code I receive the following error:

```
lgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I have tried to use the `np.linalg.solve(A,B)` method but this returns the same error.

I have also tried defining the matrices like this `B = np.array([0,120,100,40,10,60,100])` but this returns the following error:

```
    A = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0,1,0])
TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I know I must be doing something wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `A` is a singular matrix. Your `Ax=B` might not have a solution.

Comment: The two last rows of `A` are equal (making `A` forcefully singular). Maybe the last row contains a typo?  Also note that for `A = np.array([1,0....], ...)` to work, you need to put the arguments in a list (adding an extra pair of square brackets). Like `A = np.array([ [1,0....],...,[...,0] ])`